# How do I get three green squares next to each other in Tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to make 20x20 grid with three green squares next to each other like a snake with a 'for' function. In each Run and Check, the position must be different. I tried to mess around with coordinates a little. But I didn't find the solution. Can you help me?

Code:

```
import tkinter
import random

c=tkinter.Canvas()
c.pack()
c.config(width=600, height=600)

gw=26
gs=2
go="white"
gf="gray"
rf='green'

for i in range(gs,600, 30):
    for j in range(gs,600, 30):
        c.create_rectangle(i,j,i+gw,j+gw, width=gs, outline=go, fill=gf)

#this is the code for three green squares
for i in range(3):
    rx=random.randrange(gs, 600, 30)
    ry=random.randrange(gs, 600, 30)
    c.create_rectangle(rx, ry, rx+gw, ry+gw, width=gs, fill=rf, outline=go)

c.mainloop()
```

Comment: if you want the squares to be next to each other, only the first position should be chosen at random, the rest should be placed next to the first position also choosing at random but also checking if that won't go off the grid

Comment: Not an answer but a tip. Rather than drawing a green rectangle over the gray rectangle, just change the colour of the gray rectangle. This way when you have the "snake" moving, you are just changing the color of existing boxes rather than drawing new ones each time which will gradually fill up your memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code shows a method for calculating the position of the snake at random but placing the two subsequent squares next to the first.

Rather than drawing a new rectangle each time, I'm just changing the color of the squares on the grid for each "segment" of the snake.

```
import tkinter
import random

c=tkinter.Canvas()
c.pack()
c.config(width=600, height=600)

gw=26
gs=2
go="white"
gf="gray"

grid = {}

for i in range(gs,600, 30):
    for j in range(gs,600, 30):
        obj = c.create_rectangle(i,j,i+gw,j+gw, width=gs, outline=go, fill=gf)
        grid[(i//30,j//30)] = obj

#Calculate starting position of the "snake"
#Limit the starting position between 3 and 17 so that we don't go off the edge to start with
rx=random.randint(3,17)
ry=random.randint(3,17)
#Create a list of the different parts of the snake
#Item 1 is random, item 2 and 3 are the next squares over
snake = []
snake.append((rx,ry))
snake.append((rx+1,ry))
snake.append((rx+2,ry))

#Iterate over each part of the snake, and set each square to green 
for segX,segY in snake:
    rf='green'
    #c.create_rectangle(rx, ry, rx+gw, ry+gw, width=gs, fill=rf, outline=go)
    c.itemconfigure(grid[segX,segY],fill=rf)

c.mainloop()
```

when the snake grows in size, you just append a new set of coordinates to the `snake` list. To move the snake, just set a new coordinate in the list at the front, and remove the item from the end.